# Advance Search in Model (MVC)

Tags: php, search, database-abstraction

I want to create a Advance Search, something like this:

- Textbox: Find
- Dropdown: search by: name, location or telephone
- Dropdown: Order By Asc or Dec
- Dropdown: Sort by name, location or telephone
- Dropdown: Search between dates (if selected)

What is the proper way to add those parameters in the function for the model?

I have came up with this solution:

```
class ShopsModel extends Model {

  findBy($find, $searchBy, $order, $sort, $betweenDate) {
   // some MySQL query here...
  }

}
```

**Edit**: I am talking about the variables - `findBy($find, $searchBy, $order, $sort, $betweenDate)` - do I need all those parameters or is there alternative solution?

Comment: What framework are you using? Also, it's really unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: @BenLee I am talking about the variables - `findBy($find, $searchBy, $order, $sort, $betweenDate)` - do I need all those parameters or is there alternative solution?

Comment: class vars, likely not in model though. You can have a post handler that assigns the class vars by their values and then use those to construct your request. At least that way you're not having to modify method args every time you update your search code. just an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems to be ok. But you can also use decorator pattern, so you could make the following query:

```
$shops = new ShopsModel();
$results = $shops->search('name', 'Tadeck')
    ->order_by('name', 'asc')
    ->between_dates('2012-02-01', '2012-03-14')
    ->fetch_all();
```

Comment: +1, that is really good idea. I think I should have `ShopsSearchModel` for searching part only.  `ShopsModel` for editing and deleting? To put all that in one model - it will be too big. What do you think?

Comment: @user791022: It depends. I would rather stay with using single model for reading, writing and removing. Also such methods are usually parts of query builders, and you may not need a model for that. But whatever you will choose, the most important thing is to be consistent across your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are describing ought to be done in conjunction with a javascript library like knockoutjs or backbonejs.

Nettuts has covered knockoutjs and a demonstration is available here: http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/1034_ko/demo/index.html

If you are using a pattern like Yii,you can google for tutorials like this one http://aiao.be/2012/01/29/knockout-js-with-the-yii-framework-hello-world-example/